# 不特定のiframe内のclickイベントを検知したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

現在開発しているアプリケーションには、全ての画面にドロップダウン型のメニューが配置されています。
`$('html').click(function () { ... })`によってメニューを閉じる処理を記述しているのですが、問題があります。

一部の画面には`iframe`が設置されていたり、あるいは動的に生成したりしているのですが、`iframe`内でクリックした場合にメニューが閉じません。
`iframe`ごとにイベントハンドラを設定してあげればどうにでもなりそうですが、可能であれば、個別の画面に対するそのような修正は避けたいです。
全ての画面に対して汎用的に対処したいのですが、何か良い方法はあるでしょうか。

なお、対応ブラウザは、IE9+/Chrome/Edge/Safariです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` の `blur` イベントでもメニューを閉じる処理をすれば良いかと思います。

Comment: なるほど。iframeにfocusするので、メイン画面のwindowでblurが発生するのですね。